# Understanding a mistake regarding removable and essential singularity.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, fake-proofs, singularity

[It is a well known fact that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity#/media/File:Essential_singularity.png) $0$ is an essential singularity of the function $e^{1/z}$ therefore it is neither removable nor a pole.

On the other hand we know the Rieamann's continuation theorem which states that an holomorphic function $f:U\setminus \{z_0\}\to \mathbb{C}$ has a removable singularity at $ z_0$ if and only if $f(z) $ is bounded in some neighborhood of $ z_0$.

I'm confussed because of the following calculation:
If we pick $\varepsilon>0 $ and $ z$ such that $|z|<\varepsilon $ then
$$ |z e^{1/z} |< \varepsilon \sum^\infty_{k=0} \left|\frac{1}{k!z^k} \right|=\varepsilon \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{1}{k!\varepsilon^k} =\varepsilon e^{1/\varepsilon}$$
The previous means that $ 0$ is a removable singularity of $ ze^{1/z}$ which implies that $ 0$ is a pole of order 1 of $ e^{1/z}$ which cannot be since the well known fact of the begining.

Of course I'm wrong in something but I couldn't tell in what.
Thank you all in advance

**A (possibly) useful definition**
My definition of a pole is:
$z_0 $ is a pole of order $ m$ of the holomorphic function $f:U\setminus \{z_0\}\to \mathbb{C}$ if $m $ is the minimum integer such that $(z-z_0)^mf(z) $ has a removable singularity at $ z_0$.

Comment: Sure, but how what I wrote is wrong. I mean, you say  "it is wrong because it is not true: take the example $ (0,1)$" but I want to know where is the proof I posted wrong.

Comment: Ok but which step in my "proof" is wrong.

Comment: Have a look at the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first equality in the displayed equation is wrong. You replaced $|z|$ by $\epsilon$, but $|z|$ can be arbitrarily small, and hence the summands can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: But I picked $ z\in B_\varepsilon(0)$ then show that $ f$ is bounded in the open set of $  B_\varepsilon(0)$.

Comment: $|z|<\epsilon$ doesn't imply $|f(z)|<|f(\epsilon)|.$

Comment: @Natalio: I'm afraid I don't follow you. You asked for the specific step in your "proof" that's wrong. I pointed out the specific step. Please refer to that specific step if you disagree.

Comment: You are helping me a lot because you pointed that step but I don't understant why the step you pointed out  is wrong.

Comment: @Natalio: The only restriction you placed on $z$ is that $|z|\lt\epsilon$. That doesn't allow you to replace $|z|$ by $\epsilon$. If you disagree, please explain why you believe that replacement should be valid.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you very much.